# JSON result not showing when rendered

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

I have a `JSON` with the following structure :

```
{
"last_reached":false,
"error":false,
"gal_providers":
    [
        {
            "GalProvider":
                {
                    "id":"121",
                    "uid":"gp_522f1e0472eba",
                    "user_id":"45230",
                },
                "GalCategory":
                {
                    "id":"3",
                    "name":"Photographer",
                    "status":"1",
                    "added_on":"1355211746"
                }
--------------
--------------------
```

I tried to render the above JSON output as below:

```
jQuery.each(resp.gal_providers, function(index, gal_provider) {
        alert(gal_provider.GalCategory.added_on);
});
```

But the above `alert` does not show anything. Interestingly I am getting the correct result when checked locally !! Whats the problem ?

Edit 1:

Getting this error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'added_on' of undefined`

Full website link:[Website](http://ec2-54-204-69-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com/agm2/main/photographers/search)

Comment: The Website link is either slow or not working.

Comment: can you put up fiddle for this?

Comment: ' Interestingly I am getting the correct result when checked locally '. Could you expand on how you are checking locally?

Comment: @Shiva The same website, I am getting the desired output when checked in `localhost`